# Use background clip animation to full fill an image instead of text

Tags: html, css, animation, background

i'm trying to make an animation, based on filling a logo with a background image. 
I'm following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0wwJrhVJcU

I tried it with text, it works perfectly, but when trying to replace text with an image, background is filling all around but not the image

HTML

```
<div class="loader">
       <h1><img src="../../assets/logo_full_w.png" height="150px" width="300px"/></h1>

     </div>
```

CSS

```
.loader{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%)
}

.loader h1{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-size:15em;
  color:rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-image: url(../../assets/background_loader.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  -webkit-background-clip:padding-box;
  animation: animate 15s linear infinite;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: 'Coffee'
}

@keyframes animate
{
  0%
  {
    background-position: left 0px top 80px;
  }
  40%
  {
    background-position: left 800px top -50px;
  }
  80%
  {
    background-position: left 1800px top -50px;
  }
  100%
  {
    background-position: left 2400px top 80px;
  }
}
```

Screen of result :

(In case screen don't work , here's  a link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7aC6.jpg)
Thanks in advance

Comment: The transparent part will be filled so what is the transparent part of the logo?

Comment: The logo is white, only the background is transparent, should i make the content of the logo transparent and keep the borders ?